# Elastic's Logstash Mutate Split not working

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, split, logstash, dplyr

I'm having trouble splitting the http.request.referrer field in logstash.  This is coming from packet beat. I want to only use the domain and not the full path.  With the following filter, as suggested here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html, I get the following error

```
[WARN ][logstash.filters.mutate  ] Exception caught while applying mutate filter {:exception=>"Invalid FieldReference: `sfa[2]`"}
```

But if I dont try to retrieve the second element and just used the field sfa to add to sfa_ref then it works, only with the forward slashes replaced by commas.

```
filter {
  mutate {
    add_field => {"sfa" => "%{[http][request][referrer]}"}
  }
  mutate {
    split => ["sfa", "/"]
    add_field => {"sfa_ref" => "%{sfa[2]}"}
  }
}
```

input is as follows:

```
{
    "http": {
      "request": {
        "bytes": 727,
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
          "content-length": 0
        },
        "referrer": "https://example.domain.com/web/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
      },
      "response": {
        "bytes": 66989,
        "status_code": 200,
        "body": {
          "bytes": 66624
        },
        "headers": {
          "content-length": 66624,
          "content-type": "application/font-woff2"
        }
      },
      "version": "1.1"
    },
    "status": "OK"
  }
```

After the split,the `sfa` field becomes:

```
"sfa": [ "https:", "", "example.domain.com", "web", "font-awesome", "css", "font-awesome.min.css" ]
```

Comment: Can you share an example of the data in the field `sfa`? Also, to capture the **second** element you should use `%{sfa[1]}`, arrays start with zero.

Comment: It doesn't matter what index I use to get the element, 0, 1, 2, the error is the same.
I've edited the question to capture input data as requested (heavily simplified but the structure of the message is kept).
the `sfa` field is a copy of `[http][request][referrer]` field whose value is `https://example.domain.com/web/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css`

after the split,the sfa field becomes:
```"sfa": [
    "https:",
    "",
    "example.domain.com",
    "web",
    "font-awesome",
    "css",
    "font-awesome.min.css"
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation followed seems to be outdated. In the newer versions of logstash,  the proper way to address an array or elements in them is `%{[field_name][index]}`.
So I needed square brackects around the field name also.

```
mutate {
  split => ["sfa", "/"]
  add_field => {"sfa_ref" => "%{[sfa][2]}"}
}
```